# Unable to access json data in angularjs array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-http

I've successfully returned a json object which has query results from database. I'm unable to access the returned json one by one.

Here's what the `console.log` shows:
[image]

Angular code:

```
$scope.peopleList=[];
            $http.get("http://localhost/project/public/people_names").then(function(response) {
                $scope.peopleList.push(response.data);
            });
            console.log($scope.peopleList);
```

if I use `console.log($scope.peopleList[0]);`, it says `undefined`. How do I access it to print it using `ng-repeat`

Comment: That's because your are doing an asynchronous call, try with `console.log`, but inside **then**.

Comment: Instead of pushing just assign the data prop in response  object to peopleList. You can then loop over that easily with `ng-repeat`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
$scope.peopleList=[];
$http.get("http://localhost/project/public/people_names")
  .then(function(response) {
     $scope.peopleList = response.data;
     console.log($scope.peopleList);
  });
```

And use like below with `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat='person in peopleList track by person.id'>
  ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As `response.data` is already an **`array of objects`**. So, no need to push it again into the different array.
- You can directly use `$scope.peopleList = response.data` instead of `$scope.peopleList.push(response.data)`

Now, if you try to access the first object from an array you can use `console.log($scope.peopleList[0])` it will provide you the expected results.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.peopleList = [{
      id: 5, 
      name:"Raman"
    },
    {
      id: 7, 
      name:"Komal"
    }];
    console.log($scope.peopleList[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```